# Spring MappingJackson2JsonView XML Equivalent

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Using Spring, I only know of a long winded approach to having XML view via MarshallingView & Jaxb2Marshaller classes (using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver) and in which you have to not only annotate the model classes with XML, but also to specifically bound the classes that are XML annotated.

Using MappingJackson2JsonView to render json views is straighforward (no need to explicitly annotate nor bound your model classes) and it directly returns a view in json.  Is there a equivalent class to MappingJackson2JsonView for an easy setup to render the views in XML?